# Swift , UIkit - Add collection view to toolBar, GalleryApp

Tags: swift, gallery, toolbar

i want to create a photo gallery view. I would like to look like a photo gallery in iPhone.

[image]

I have a problem with adding a collection view to toolbar. If I add only one image as UIImageView , everything works but when I add collection view, view not appear

This is my code - help

```
    let toolbar = ToolBarCollectionView()
    toolbar.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    toolbar.view.frame = navigationController?.toolbar.frame ?? CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 25, height: 25)
    let item = UIBarButtonItem(customView: toolbar.view)
    setToolbarItems([item], animated: false)
    navigationController?.toolbar.setShadowImage(UIImage(), forToolbarPosition: .bottom)
```

Comment: The Apple Developer website has a great sample project you can download here https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/views_and_controls/collection_views/implementing_modern_collection_views with examples for many different uses of collection views

Comment: my collection view works fine but I have problem to add CollectionView to the toolbar

Comment: What is `ToolBarCollectionView()`?  When I type that, Xcode says it can't find it in scope.  If this is a custom class you've defined yourself, it might be helpful to include that code in your question as well.

Comment: ToolBarCollectionView is my UICollectionVIew